# How to show normality of the subgroup by conjugating it with generators of the group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G=\langle a,b| aba^{-1} = b^5\rangle.$ Show that $H=\langle b \rangle$ is normal. 
>  
>   Hint: Show what happens when you conjugate an element of $H$ by the generators of $G.$

**My attempt:**
Let $h=b^n \in H, n \in \mathbb Z$, then $aHa^{-1}=ab^na^{-1}=aba^{-1}ab^{n-1}a^{-1}=b^5ab^{n-1}a^{-1}=\text{continuing the same way} = b^{5n} \in H.$ 
$bHb^{-1} = bb^nb^{-1} = b^n \in H.$
Is this correct?

So if we conjugate $H$ with the generators of $G$, we still stay in H. But that doesn't show that $H$ is normal, since we have to check for all elements in $G$. How do we proceed?

Comment: But all elements of $G$ can be written as some product of the generators, so iteratively performing multiple instances of the two cases you have completed above would ultimately yield an element in $H$ still.

Answer (score 1):

Define a map $c\colon G\to \operatorname{Aut} G$ by $c(g)(x) = gxg^{-1}$. If $g,h\in G$, then $$c(gh)(x) = (gh)x(gh)^{-1} = g(hxh^{-1})g^{-1} = (c(g)\circ c(h))(x),\ \forall x\in G,$$
so $c$ is a group homomorphism. That means that if $\{g_1,\ldots,g_n\}$ are generators of $G$, and $c(g_i)H = H,\ i = 1,\ldots, n,$ then for any $g\in G$, write $g = g_{i_1}g_{i_2}\ldots g_{i_k}$ and you have $$c(g)(h) = c(g_{i_1}g_{i_2}\ldots g_{i_k})(h) = (c(g_{i_1})c(g_{i_2})\ldots c(g_{i_k}))(h)\in H.$$